# making jQuery UI tabs bookmarkable

Tags: jquery-ui

I find it a bit weird that the jQuery UI tabs don't have a built-in convenience method for making the tabs bookmarkable (change the URL hash). The following snippet kinda works for me

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    "activate": function(event, ui) {
        window.location.hash = ui.newTab.context.hash;
    }
});
```

The problem is, when the hash is appended to the URL, the page jumps to the corresponding anchor on the page. How can I prevent that from happening? All I want is for the URL address to change showing the currently selected tab, but not move the page vertically.

**Update:** Just to be clear, I am not wedded to my code above. I am just interested in being able to change the URL address bar with the selected tab's id so the user can bookmark or link the tab.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `window.location.hash` (which refreshes the page) with HTML5 history (which manipulates the URL address bar and the browser history stack without refreshing the page) did the trick for me. The following code worked for me

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    "activate": function(event, ui) {
        var url = window.location;
        window.history.pushState({
            "html": "",
            "pageTitle": title,
        }, "", url.href.replace(url.hash, "") + ui.newTab.context.hash);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just store your current vertical scrolling distance to the page's top and reapply it afterwards, like this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    "activate": function(event, ui) {'use strict';
        var scrollTop;   

        scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
        window.location.hash = ui.newTab.context.hash;
        $(document).scrollTop(scrollTop);
    }
});
```